Caption of \subcaptionbox environment not correctly centered
I am using \subcaptionbox{} to setup a figure containing multiple subfigures. I want to refer to each subfigure in the text, so each subfigure needs a caption. I want to have empty captions, meaning only "(a)", "(b)" etc., but no text. However, when using \subcaptionbox{}, the subcaption "(a)" is not centered correctly under the figure, but slightly offset to the left. This does not happen when I use the \subfigure{} environment instead of \subcaptionbox{}, but I want to keep using \subcaptionbox{} to have more control for centering subfigures vertically. Is there an easy fix to center the caption text horizontally?
Minimal example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:a}}
        {
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SE!
Before image jou have space, consequently image is pushed to right. Elimenate this space by inserting % after curly brace before inserting Picture (see MWE below):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:a}}
        {% <---
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}



Thank you very much!
